# Keeping external MySQL database updated with production data

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I have a site with both a production version (something.com) and a staging version not accessible to public used for testing / verification. The issue is that a lot of the testing is specific to the data which changes rapidly on production, making the staging database outdated fairly quickly. At first I would manually use `mysqldump` once or twice a week to back up the production DB and reimport it on staging. Now that the data on the live site changes a lot quicker, doing this only once a week isn't enough and the whole process is a bit tedious.

I'm thinking there has to be a way to automatically do this. I'm thinking I could make the staging DB accessible from the production server and write a script that dumps the production database and overwrites staging, put that in a nightly cron job and be done with it. The database is quite big though (last backup was over 400 megs) so I was wondering if maybe there would be a way to do incremental updates? There are multiple tables and the data isn't necessarily dated (for instance, it isn't user accounts with a `created_on` field) so I'm not really sure if finding all the operations done during a specific time span is doable. Maybe there's a trigger that could log all the operations, which could then be run on the staging DB nightly?

If it's of any help, the database is for a Symfony 2 application.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at MySQL replication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Even if that doesn't directly work the logs can be transferred to the staging db and imported there, giving you incremental updates.

Comment: If you're using AWS RDS they take regular snapshots and you can easily update any RDS instance with a snapshot,  The snapshots also load very quickly and it's very easy to do though the AWS web console.  By far the easiest and best method I've seen.